# Delegates & Event Listener slow/delay randomly

Tags: wpf, events, delegates, operating-system

I have develop a `WPF` Kiosk application with `delegates and event handler`. I follow the tutorial from http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx and everything is working fine.

But when i deploy it to my testing device in `Win7 32 Bit` platform, i getting some issue and found out cause by event listener is not receiving any signal immediately after the event is fired. It takes around 30 seconds to 120 seconds then only receive the signal.

Through out some testing, I found out the issue only happen after the application did 80 to 90 successful transaction.

I did check on Windows Event Viewer and there is no any error raised when the issue occurred.

I have carried some testing and get different result:
1. Restart **application** around 70 transaction made, but the issue still occur.
2. Restart **entire PC** around 70 transaction made, no issue occur anymore for the day.

What actually the OS did in background when a event is fired? Is there any quota for event which handle by OS level?

Codes in below:

**Class for Cash Machine (fooClass)**
*Declaring delegate and events*

```
public delegate void NotifyStatusEventHandler(CmsMode mode, bool isError, string sRemark);
public event NotifyStatusEventHandler NotifyStatus;
```

*Firing events*

```
this.NotifyStatus(CmsMode.Deposit_Amount_Changed, false, _inputAmount);
```

Before I execute this code, I logged down the time.

**Code In Application**
*Subscribing events*

```
fooClass foo = new fooClass();
foo.NotifyStatus += new fooClass.NotifyStatusEventHandler(CmsEventListener);
```

*Event Listener*

```
void CmsEventListener(CmsMode mode, bool isError, string sRemark)
{
    switch (mode)
    {
        case CmsMode.Deposit_Amount_Changed:
        ...(Update UI and others)
        'I did logged down time after application receive signal' 
        break;
        ...(others cases)
    }
}
```

Is there any reason that might cause this or anyway I can do debugging for this issue?

Comment: It's very hard to know what's going on without seeing any code at all. Please do diagnostic work to reduce this to a [mcve].